# Running a power shell command from batch files throws exception

Tags: powershell, batch-file

When I run the below powershell command from powershell to get the app version, I get the correct response

```
(Get-Item "C:\\Program Files\\CompanyName\\AppName\\bin\\AppLauncher.exe").VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

However I need to run it from batch file so I add the following in my batch file.

```
powershell -Command " & (Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files\\CompanyName\\AppName\\bin\\AppLauncher.exe').VersionInfo.FileVersion"
```

On executing this, I see the version being returned on the console but with exception

```
& : The term '1.2.0.33' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:4
+  & (Get-Item 'C:\\Program Files\\CompanyName\\AppName ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (1.2.0.33:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

'1.2.0.33' in the above error is the version I am expecting it to return.

Also if it could be suggested as to how to get this assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use either:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Item \"%ProgramFiles%\CompanyName\AppName\bin\AppLauncher.exe\").VersionInfo.FileVersion"
```

Or:

```batch-file
@%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Item \"$Env:ProgramFiles\CompanyName\AppName\bin\AppLauncher.exe\").VersionInfo.FileVersion"
```

If you want to save it as a variable then perhaps:

```batch-file
@For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Item \"%ProgramFiles%\CompanyName\AppName\bin\AppLauncher.exe\").VersionInfo.FileVersion"') Do @Set VerInfo=%%G
```

or:

```batch-file
@For /F %%G In ('%__AppDir__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "(Get-Item \"$Env:ProgramFiles\CompanyName\AppName\bin\AppLauncher.exe\").VersionInfo.FileVersion"') Do @Set VerInfo=%%G
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfect on the local machine. Now I would like to get this on a remote machine where my path would be like \\192.168.0.11\c$\\Program Files\... how do I get that?

Comment: @AmitChouksey, I've already covered two questions in one, and as you've revealed that it works perfectly, please mark it as accepted. If you have a new question, then ask a new question, my answering of your initial post does not tie me into a support deal for every other question you have moving forward.